# Django Rest Framework is throwing 400 before I can handle exception for ModelViewSet

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a user model in my app with a unique field on email. However, I need to catch when a user is trying to do a duplicate request so I can do some processing in a different way.

I am making a POST call to create this user.
DRF of course throws a 400 with an existing email message.

But even when I create a validate_email method in my model or try to catch it with a custom exception it doesn't catch.

I created a custom ValidationError cause the general ValidationError didn't seem to have a way to filter it out specifically besides a generic code, `unique`, or matching the message string.

**How can I catch this specific validation in Django Rest Framework?**

Error Message:

```
{
    "email": [
        "user with this email address already exists."
    ],
    "status_code": 400
}
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    User Model
    """

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=30, blank=True)

    def validate_email(self):
       email = self.email
       valid_email = email is not None and email.endswith(self.email_domain)
       if not valid_email:
           raise ValidationError(
               _("Email is not valid"),
               code="invalid.email",
           )

       if Users.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
           import ipdb; ipdb.sset_trace() #does not get called 
           raise EmailExists()
```

UserViewSet code:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return UserSerializer
        else:
            return UserDetailSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except EmailExists:
            logger.debug('caught the existing email')
            import ipdb; ipdb.sset_trace()
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

custom exception:

```
   from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

   class EmailExists(ValidationError):
      """Raised when user exists"""
      pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture a `ValidationError` exception instead. The reason behind this is because you've defined your email field `unique=True` and Django will automatically check that when you call `serializer.is_valid()`.

In addition, you can check for unique constraint error by using `exc. get_full_details()`

```py
try:
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
except ValidationError as exc:
    errors = exc.get_full_details()
    if 'email' in errors and errors['email']['code'] == 'unique':
        # do something, maybe re-raise with your custom exception:
        raise EmailExists from exc
```

**Ref**

- [Exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#inspecting-api-exceptions)
- [Unique constraint error code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/5b2abbed25ef41c4cc1b3806037c6bd7631db327/rest_framework/validators.py#L74)

Comment: ah see I was trying to see if there was a cleaner way to do this than matching strings from the error code. So I tried to create and capture unique on my own by overriding  the create() function in the viewset but if this is the cleanest way then I guess I'll have to do it. 
Wished DRF had more meaningful exceptions though tbh. 
Thank you. I'll try this and then accept the answer once I check in my code review that this is the best way.

Comment: Yeah, handle the uniqueness on your own is also an option but I'd suggest you to handle it in `validate()` (or even `validate_email()`) instead. That would be better. I also agree with you that DRF doesn't do much about capturing unique error.

Comment: Honestly, I tried that already with this exception. Your way might be the simplest method rn unless I need to capture more unique conditions and do diff processing on each one. But in this case, it's just this one condition.